# Can someone please port this question about the use of registers to this stackexchange?

Tags: support

There's a really [great question and answer about the use of vi registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-to-use-vim-registers) on stackexchange, but it belongs here...can someone move it here?

Comment: Also related: [What do we do with questions that are already answered somewhere else on SE?](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-are-already-answered-somewhere-else-on-se) ...

Comment: That being said, if you do feel that a question should be migrated to the vi.SE site, then you should flag it for moderator attention, and explain why you think it's off-topic and should be migrated. Posting a question about it here is most definitely the 'wrong' thing to do, since we're not Stack Overflow moderators and don't have the ability to move questions from SO ;-) Most of the times, a question should *not* be migrated though (see above 2 links).

Comment: @leeand00 Older questions than 60 days can't be migrated. See: [What is migration and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/191655)